# How to insert code in monaco editor using the protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, protractor, monaco-editor

I'm trying to use protractor to test the code containing monaco editor, and can't find how to edit the code programmatically.

This my test

```
import {CodelabPage} from './app.po';
import {browser, element, by} from 'protractor';

describe('codelab App', function () {
  let page: CodelabPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new CodelabPage();
  });

  it('should display message saying app works', () => {
      page.navigateTo();
      page.openMilestone(1);
      page.openExercise('TypeScript');
      browser.pause(2000);
      page.editCode('Dog.ts', `HopHeyLalalay`);
      browser.pause();
    }
  );
});
```

This my functions

```
import {browser, element, by} from 'protractor';
import {By} from "protractor/built/index";

export class CodelabPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }

  getMilestoneDescriptionText() {
    element(by.css('.milestone')).click();

    return element(by.css('.description')).getText();
  }

  getElementText(nameElement) {
    return element(by.css(nameElement)).getText();
  }


  openMilestone(index) {
    return element(by.cssContainingText('.milestone', index)).click();
  }

  openExercise(text) {
    return element(by.cssContainingText('.exercise', text)).click();
  }

  editCode(filename: string, code: string) {
    return element(by.css('.monaco-editor-background textarea'))
      .sendKeys('njnj');
  }
}
```

Help to understand how to edit the code in Monaco or just paste the code in Monaco.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monaco editor exposes an API which you can use to edit the text area. You can try this:

```
  browser.executeScript('this.monaco.editor.getModels()[0].setValue("' + yourStringHere + '"));
```

In case you're using an iframe, you will need to switch to the iframe before trying to edit the code, like this:

```
browser.switchTo().frame(iframeSelector);
```